# Import Google Maps' CDN link into a ReactJs project

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, cdn

I made a project using 'create-react-app' that uses ReactJs, Node and Babel. I want to be able to access Google Map's variables within React components, but since the CDNs in the HTML get loaded after the components, they are not available in time.

I found no other way to import Google Maps (such as npm), so I need to figure out how to load an external file to import to my React Classes.

Furthermore, I read something about importing it to the webpack file, but I am not sure how to do this either.

Answer (score 1):

it has a lot of work ...

First of all you import the lib from cdn on your index.html

```
/* imports */

let google = window.google;
let mapProp = {
    /* props */
};

export class Map extends React.Component { 
/* code */

 componentDidMount() {
        /*addChangeListener*/
        let node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        let map = new google.maps.Map(node, this.state.mapProp);
        this.setState({map}); //this.initialize(map);
        /* this.mountPath(map) your logic to mount map*/;
    }

}
```

For me work, I hope to have helped.